# Displaying the author of next and previous posts in pagination?

Tags: pagination, author, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I have set up links to the next/previous posts on my `single.php` template. Currently I am using `<?php previous_post_link(); ?>` and `<?php next_post_link(); ?>` which gives me the title of the next/previous posts, but I would also like to be able to display the author of those posts below the title. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Change `<?php previous_post_link(); ?>` and `<?php next_post_link(); ?>` with the following code:

For previous post:

```
  <?php
    $prev_post = get_previous_post();
    $prev_user = get_user_by( 'id', $prev_post->post_author );
    if (!empty( $prev_post )): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $prev_post->guid ?>"><?php echo $prev_post->post_title ?> (<?php echo $prev_user->first_name . ' ' . $prev_user->last_name; ?>)</a>
    <?php endif ?>
```

For next post:

```
  <?php
    $next_post = get_next_post();
    $next_user = get_user_by( 'id', $next_post->post_author );
    if (!empty( $prev_post )): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $next_post->guid ?>"><?php echo $next_post->post_title ?> (<?php echo $next_user->first_name . ' ' . $next_user->last_name; ?>)</a>
    <?php endif ?>
```

You also can control from which categories WordPress should select previous and next posts. `get_previous_post` and `get_next_post` accept two parameters:

- `(bool) $in_same_cat` — prev/next posts will be selected from the same category as you current post
- `(string) $excluded_categories` — posts related to these categories will be skipped

More details about these parameters you may [find here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post)

Comment: Thank you, that worked a treat! Will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom function. For this you need to use

```
// Add in single.php where you want to show next icon.
$nextPost = get_next_post();    // Get the next post detail
$nextPostID = $nextPost->ID;    // Get the post id of next post and pass it 
echo get_post_link_with_post_author_name( $nextPostID );
```

And define the `get_post_link_with_post_author_name()` in your active theme's functions.php as :

```
// This function returns postname, post author and link to it.
function get_post_link_with_post_author_name( $postID ){
    // you have got the postID , now you need to fetch the post name, post url and post author
   $post = get_post( $postID );      
   $post_title = $post->post_title;
   $post_author_id = $post->post_author;
   $author_detail = get_user_by( 'ID', $post_author_id );
   $post_author_name = $author_detail->display_name;
   $post_url = get_permalink( $postID );
   $respone = "<a href='$post_url'>$post_title >> By $post_author_name</a>";
   return $response;
}
```

You can use the same function for previous post link with post name and author name. You just need to get the previous post id using `get_previous_post()` and pass that post id to the above function.